# GeneratorsNeeded error in sympy extracting coefficients of polynomial

Tags: python, sympy

This is the error I am getting:

> **Exception has occurred: GeneratorsNeeded**
> can't initialize from 'dict' without generators

when I try to extract coefficients from a polynomial

I have two variables `expr` and `sol` which holds the strings of the expressions `'2*x-y'` and `'-4'` respectively where `x` and `y`  I am required to extract the coefficients from each of the variables and merge them into a list that is held by a variable named `eq`.

This is my approach below:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import sympify

expr = '2*x-y'
sol = '-4'
expr = sp.Poly(sympify(expr)).coeffs()
sol = sp.Poly(sympify(sol)).coeffs()
eq = expr + sol
print(eq)
```

I expected the result of my code to be a list of the coefficients from both variables, `expr` and `sol`

Expected outcome:

```
[2,-1,-4]
```

The error occurs at this line

```
sol = sp.Poly(sympify(sol)).coeffs()
```

Any pointers are hugely appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `Poly(-4)` raises because there is no generator (variable) for the polynomial. You can provide generators as separate arguments e.g. `Poly(-4, [x, y])` (where x and y are symbols).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, however, I would also like to know if there other alternatives than providing generators for the separate polynomial.

Comment: A Poly has to have a generator. You can use a random symbol as the generator. If you have multiple expressions that you want to convert to Poly using the same generators you can use `parallel_poly_from_expr`.